# What is meant by "private": true, or "private": false, in package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json

I'm Using a Core UI template in `package.json` file, I'm not very sure about this line of code why is this for or what's the main purpose.

```
...
  "private": true, 
...
```

What if I turn this into false or what if I remove it . ? I found on web there is something about publication but I'm still not very sure .

Answer (score 3):

False value means that your package will be available on npmjs.com for all. True means that your package will be available for those users who you grant access to if your pricing plan on npmjs allows it.

Comment: `true` would mean that it _won't_ be available publicly, while `false` would mean that it _will_ be available publicly.